# launching a test project from another application

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-testing

I have created a test project for one of android app. This test project also creates an excel file with some content. Now, every time i have to run the app, I have to connect my device and run it through eclipse. However, I need to generate the excel whenever I want (on the go).

But my test app doesn't show up in the launcher(obviously). I can only see the test project installed at, **Settings-->Apps-->All**. And hence I cannot even tap and launch. (First problem)

**My Approach** :  I thought of creating a separate android app with one or two buttons and invoking the test app with `onClickListner` event. But again, the new app is unable to find the test class.

This is my code :

```
private OnClickListener launchListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.org.search.test","com.org.search.test.MyTestClassName"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    };
```

And below is the exception log:

```
03-10 17:05:44.185: E/AndroidRuntime(22195): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class      {com.org.search.test/com.org.search.test.MyTestClassName}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
at com.expedia.pb.activity.ScrapeActivity$2.onClick(ScrapeActivity.java:49)
```

Adding `Android Manifest file`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pb.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/PB_APP"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pb.activity.ScrapeActivity"
            android:label="@string/PB_APP" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity  
            android:name="com.org.search.test.MyTestClassName">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone please help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: If you have not declared launcher tag in your test project then you will not able to open it in any way.

Comment: please post menifest code of your test project

Answer (score 0):

It shows that you forget to declare `com.org.search.test.MyTestClassName` in your manifest file.

Make sure you have regiestered your `MyTestClassName` activity in your manifest file as below:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MyTestClassName"
        android:label="@string/basic_map" />
```

Comment: What is your actual package ?

Comment: My Application which has the onClickListener, the package name is there in the manifest. And the package name to be launched is there inside code.

Answer (score 0):

Add category as launcher in your test activity. launch icon will be displayed in your homescreen.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.pb.activity.ScrapeActivity"
        android:label="@string/PB_APP" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity  
        android:name="com.org.search.test.MyTestClassName">
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>
```